# Switching Mercurial Projects (Bitbucket) to Git (Github)

Tags: git, mercurial

I am trying to move my public projects from bitbucket to github.

I see that [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/) extension will help me get this done.

```
$ easy_install hg-git

Searching for hg-git
Best match: hg-git 0.3.0
Processing hg_git-0.3.0-py2.7.egg
hg-git 0.3.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hg_git-0.3.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for hg-git
Searching for dulwich>=0.8.1
```

why? from [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/) official website I see that 0.8.1 is not even out yet.

```
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/dulwich/
Reading http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich
Reading http://launchpad.net/dulwich
No local packages or download links found for dulwich>=0.8.1
```

If I try the more involved way as mentioned on [github](http://hg-git.github.com/)

I get dulwich 0.8.0 installed

```
$ which dulwich                                                                                 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/dulwich
```

I clone the hg-git repository and properly link it from my hgrc. However when I try using hg-git it complains

```
*** failed to import extension hggit from ~/.bin/hg-git/hggit: No module named dulwich.errors
```

So, apparantly I am not able to install hg-git, and I am stuck.

---

UPDATE

```
>>> import dulwich
>>> import dulwich.errors
>>> dulwich.errors
<module 'dulwich.errors' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich-0.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/dulwich/errors.pyc'>
>>> dulwich
<module 'dulwich' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich-0.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/dulwich/__init__.pyc'>
```

---

Comment: Try to ask on [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/hg-git) again. It was already reported, but the maintainer (who even acknowledged it) made a release on the next day, so if it's still wrong, it probably makes sense to remind it again.

Comment: Why don't you use [hg-fast-export](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

used [hg-fast-export](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git) following [Dan's tutorial](http://hivelogic.com/articles/converting-from-mercurial-to-git/)

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try to use [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). They include a working version of dulwich, and you'd only need to specify the path to hg-git.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently someone just bumped the dependency requirement for the project 2 days ago:

https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/changeset/81f42c0d5ea9

As for your error - what happens if you run `python` and type `import dulwich`, and then `import dulwich.errors`? What messages do you get? It may be that for some reason, the version of dulwich you have installed isn't in the module search path being used by Mercurial's tools - you could try adjusting `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I am really getting no clue, can you help, hmm?

Comment: Is your `PYTHONPATH` env var set to anything in particular?

Comment: Well, it looks like a new version of `hg-git` has been released that corrects the dependency to `0.8.0` (https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/changeset/78ca06c40b90), so why not try installing via `easy_install` again and see if that works better.